Is it necessary to upgrade Angular project to the latest stable version?
We have a very big project written in Angular. We would like to be up to date with all the libraries we are using. While we try to upgrade Angular from 16 to 17 we face a lot of code refactoring...
My question, is it really necessary? What are the points that I should take into account? Can I ignore it and leave the project on Angular 16 forever?

You can keep any software going at whatever version you want. I know people who are still running Windows XP. You will pay a price for that. You can't upgrade anything around Angular (e.g., Node.js, npm, versions of any dependencies) to keep up with vulnerabilities found, so your system becomes ever more insecure as time goes on. There are many other risks. So many it would be too many to list in an answer.

The Angular team supports each version for 18 months (6 month active + 12 month of LTS for security fixed).
The major downside you'll experience is not having access to any of the new features.
For example, the new control flow syntax is only available from v17 onwards.

I would argue that getting no more security patches after the LTS period has ended is a more important downside than not having access to new features.

To my knowledge, yes. I have some projects less than a year old that have gotten deprecated and I can no longer even run them as the syntaxes in them are no longer supported. For example, the app-routing.module.ts has now changed to app.routes.ts. The code syntax also seems new.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
